# WPF application unable to resolve resource name and locate resource at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

So a few things to establish before I get into the meat of things:

- I'm using .NET 4.0 without having the option to upgrade
- I'm limited to VS2010 for my IDE
- My application uses the MVVM pattern
- It involves a launcher application as a gateway to the underlying apps, which is the intended end-user UX flow
- The code is split between multiple projects within the same solution
- When I launch the problematic application as standalone, it works perfectly fine; It has issues when I launch it from the launcher application though
- The launcher launches the application in a separate window, as a separate process

In essence what the underlying app is meant for is generating and filling out reports with different types of clauses to be checked off (Text, numeric, alphanumeric) and have different data fields, due to which there are a handful of templates for the data to be displayed appropriately in the View.
The issue is when my application is putting together the View to show the generated report, it fails to find the Template Picker.

My base project contains reusable user controls and ViewModels that are reused in the report generation apps. This is where the UserControl for the ListBox for each item in the report's list of items is located. This is also where the C# class for the TemplatePicker is located.

My Condition Report project contains the views for the report-builder application, as well as the styles used across this report-builder. It has it's Models and ViewModels stored in separate projects respectively. This is where the XAML definition for the TemplatePicker is located.

This is the code for the CustomListBox where it references my TemplatePicker.

```
<xmlns:ConditionsPicker="clr-namespace:eSOCs.Base.Helpers;assembly=eSOCs.Base"/>
 
<ListBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedCondition}"  
                 Grid.Row="5" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="9" 
                 Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.ConditionsListBoxVisibility, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.ConditionsForGroup}"
                 ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ConditionTemplatePicker}" Margin="1,6,-1,117"
            x:Name="ListBoxConditions">
```

This is the code excerpt from my DataTemplates.xaml which is the xaml definition for my TemplatePicker (ConditionsListTemplatePicker is the c# class for the template picker):

```
<xmlns:ConditionsPicker="clr-namespace:eSOCs.Base.Helpers;assembly=eSOCs.Base"/>

<ConditionsPicker:ConditionsListTemplatePicker x:Key="ConditionTemplatePicker"
                                                    DefaultConditionTemplate="{StaticResource DefualtCondiditonTemplate}" 
                                                    TextMessageConditionTemplate="{StaticResource TextCondiditonTemplate}" 
                                                    PolymerConditionTemplate="{StaticResource PolymerSourceTemplate}" 
                                                    RecoveryConditionTemplate="{StaticResource PolymerSourceTemplate}"
                                                    TextConditionTemplate="{StaticResource ConditionTextDataTemplate}"/>
```

And this is my App.xaml for the report-builder app adding to the ResourceDictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Strings.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Labels.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Canvas.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/TextBlock.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Borders.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/ListBox.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Buttons.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Windows.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/ComboBox.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/ProgressBar.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/CustomKeypadStyle.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/CustomSelectionPopup/CustomPopupTextBoxStyle.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/DataTemplates.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

This is the code that performs the process-creation from within the context of the launcher:

```
public void BringExeToForeground(string exeLocation, string processName)
        {
            try
            {
                Process window = null;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BaseLine.StandardConditionsConnectionString) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(BaseLine.EsocsConnectionString) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(BaseLine.ElogConnectionString))
                {
                    var process = GetProcess(processName);
                    if (process == null)
                    {
                        ProcessStartInfo startArgs = new ProcessStartInfo();
                        startArgs.FileName = exeLocation;
                        startArgs.Arguments = BaseLine.LineNumber + " " + BaseLine.DeviceVersion + " " + BaseLine.ApplicationVersion;
                        Process.Start(startArgs);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        BringProcessToFront(process);
                    }
                }
                else if (!CheckIfProcessIsAlreadyRunning(processName))
                {
                    window = Process.Start(exeLocation);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogSystem.LogSystem.LogMessage(LogSystem.LogSystemMessageTypes.Exception, ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString(), ex.GetType().Name);
            }
        }
```

Despite all of this, I have an exception thrown at runtime because CustomListBox cannot resolve the TemplatePicker resource.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe I didn't read careful enough, but I don't understand, how the transition from the launcher application to the report application happens... is the launcher creating a separate process where the report application starts, or is the report application somehow "launched" as in opening the report app window within the launcher process?

Comment: @grek40 Yes, it launches a separate process for the report builder and has it's own window. I've edited the post to include this info, good catch!

Comment: So basically, when you launch the report builder from the launcher process creation, it starts with ressource issues, but if you launch the report builder with exact same launch parameters from some shell (cmd, powershell) it works?

Comment: @grek40 That is correct

Comment: Can you verify whether Application is used in both cases? eg. hook into the `Application.Startup` event and write some log entry? It's a really strange issue... is it limited to the report builder or do other applications also have problem with global resources when started from the launcher? Maybe you can show the launcher code that creates the report builder process?

Comment: @grek40 Other applications launched through this launcher have the same issue. The startup code is called as a RelayCommand defined within a class that derives from 'Application'. It references another class for the actual code though, and the RelayCommand is just a wrapper for performing validation and referencing the executableBase class, which performs process-related operations. I'll update the post with the process creation code from the executableBase.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. With "Application" in my last comment I meant the `App.xaml` and `App.xaml.cs` within the report builder... the one where your resources are defined. I want to know whether its Startup event fires when running from the launcher

Comment: The `Process.Start(startArgs);` part of your launcher doesn't look very suspicious... however it seems most of the time, problems related to Process Start are resolved by setting the `startArgs.WorkingDirectory` explicitly... might be worth to try.

Comment: @grek40 Having just tested it, I can confirm that the Application_Startup is called even when launching through the launcher.

Comment: @grek40 Also, setting the working directory to Environment.CurrentDirectory did not help

Comment: I really wanted to help, but I'm out of ideas right now... if you could reproduce the problem in a smaller setup without business specific code (so you can add the full example to the question) there might be more options, but given the compexity of your project, I just don't know what I would need to know in order to proceed^^